# Permission of using curlftpfs on Ubuntu

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, ftp, permission-denied, curlftpfs

I use

```
$sudo curlftpfs –o allow_other alpha:1234  @192.168.1.100 /home/alpha/share
```

to mount ftp folder as a local folder in Ubuntu 12.04

and then I can read and edit files in that folder

but I can't add a new file in this folder with Matlab

Here's the situation

I use Matlab to plot a png file in this folder

but Matlab told me that it don't have permission to create new file in this folder

so I check with `$ls -al` amd it give me following info:

```
drwxr-xr-x  1 root  root    1024  1??  1  1970 share
```

When I want to modify my code and data it's works!

But when creating a new pic with Matlab it's always give me the permission problem

I have tried

```
sudo chomd 777 /home/alpha/share
```

It's give me error below:

```
chmod: changing permissions of ??/home/alpha/share??: Operation not permitted
```

Even I try it with root account

how to fix it??

Comment: The questions might be better at http://askubuntu.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "Be aware that some applications might not
be able to "save" files on curlftpfs from 0.9.2 on, because
we don't support open(read+write) or open(write) and seek
anymore"

https://sourceforge.net/p/curlftpfs/discussion/542750/thread/53e47b71/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CurlFtpFs is a FUSE mount.  To allow a user other than the mounter to access a FUSE mount, there are flags `allow_other` and `allow_root`.  Your `sudo` implies that root is the mounter, so only root can access it.

You could use the `allow_other` flag, but in your case I would add `fuse` to your list of groups.  Then mount the FTP without `sudo`.