# Chmod fails when using fuse mount as media directory

Tags: django, docker, mount, fuse, curlftpfs

I'm trying to use a remote FTP as a Django media source in docker.

I have mounted a directory:

```
/mnt/ftp_media
```

with curlftpfs:

```
curlftpfs -o allow_other user:pass@host /mnt/ftp_media
```

I've noticed that when trying to upload a file, it actually does get created on the remote, but django fails on chmod with:

```
Operation not permitted
```

I've tried to directly execute chmod inside the mount:

```
cd /mnt/ftp_mount
chmod 666 some_file.txt
```

But then I also get an error:

```
chmod: changing permissions of 'some_file.txt': Operation not permitted
```

Even as a root user. I've tried to remount with different users, but it always yields the same results. Is it just that you should not use chmod in fuse mounts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permission of using curlftpfs on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428316/permission-of-using-curlftpfs-on-ubuntu)

Comment: @OrenKishon not exactly, or I'm simply missing something :) I've tried to mount the ftp as root, with allow_other flag, yet I still can't perform "chmod"(which I need) on files.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/36953

Comment: Note that curlftpfs has been abandoned for a really long time. `rclone` would be modern alternative with the capability to mount ftp shares.